# Java Efficient Way to sort a collection of bean

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a list of bean coming from the db as a result of querying.

The bean is as follows:

```
    public class Employee implements Comparator<Employee> {

    protected String empId; //alphanumeric e.g.abc123
    protected String empFullName;   
    protected String empAddress;
    protected String dept;
    protected String project;

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getEmpFullName() {
        return empFullName;
    }
    public void setEmpFullName(String empFullName) {
        this.empFullName = empFullName;
    }
    public String getEmpAddress() {
        return empAddress;
    }
    public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
        this.empAddress = empAddress;
    }
    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }
    public String getProject() {
        return project;
    }
    public void setProject(String project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        if (e1 == null && e2 == null) return 0; 

        if (e1 != null && e2 == null) return -1;
        if (e1 == null && e2 != null) return 1;

        return e1.empId.compareTo (e2.empId); 
    }



}
```

I have comparator which sorts by empId which is alphanumeric.

I want to know what is the best way to sort it by empId,dept,project.

In the code if I do as follows, it sorts by empId.

```
    List<Employee> empList = someDao.getEmpList();
    Collections.sort(empList, new Employee());
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an odd declaration in itself:

```
public class Employee implements Comparator<Employee>
```

It would be much more common to have:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
```

and then maybe:

```
public class EmployeeByIdComparator implements Comparator<Employee>
```

and

```
public class EmployeeByNameComparator implements Comparator<Employee>
```

etc.

An instance of a class implementing `Comparable` knows how to compare *itself* with another instance; typically this is reserved for a "natural" ordering. Compare that with an instance of `Comparator`, which knows how to compare *two instances* usually of a *different* type (the one specified as the type argument for `Comparator`).

So if you want multiple types of comparison, create multiple comparators. You may then want to chain them together - [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) provides an easy way of doing this. (See [`ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html).) For convenience, you may want to implement the comparators as private static classes within `Employee`, then expose single instances of them via public static final fields:

```
public class Employee
{
    public static final Comparator<Employee> BY_ID_COMPARATOR
        = new ByIdComparator();

    private static final class ByIdComparator : Comparator<Employee>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon Thanks, so you think this is not right, i.e.  
public class Employee implements Comparator<Employee>

Comment: @Nomad: As I said, that's extremely odd. It's very rarely a good idea. I mean, it *works* - but it's not a good separation of concerns.

Comment: Jon the reason i have comparator is because the value might be null, i think comparable doesn't take care of that. so what's why i had the comparactor there.

Comment: @Nomad: Then implement `Comparator` in a separate class, as I've suggested. (On the other hand, I suspect `Comparable` *should* actually work okay - I'd expect `Collections.sort` to take care of it and avoid either calling `compareTo` on a null value, or passing null to `compareTo`.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, Unfortunately i can't use Guava at the moment. How would you answer change if i want to go for a vanilla implementation? So you think null be taken care by the comparable. I think it might cause an error or the sorting of null values might not work.

Comment: @Nomad: I'd implement something like `ComparisonChain` myself - something that can chain comparators together, basically. (It's simple, really - perform the comparison using the first comparator. If that returns a non-zero value, that's the overall result. Otherwise, move on to the next comparator and perform the comparison that way, etc.)

Comment: thanks a lot, do you have example for ComparisonChain and how would i use it. Thanks

Comment: @Nomad: Well did you try looking at the documentation I linked to? You'll need to do some research and thinking for yourself...

Comment: I looked at the ComparisonChain you provided for Guava . But i am going for a vanilla implementation. Also another concern was thread safety.

Comment: @Nomad: Well you wouldn't be mutating any state, so it's hard to see how thread-safety is an issue - and you asked: "Do you have an example for ComparisonChain and how would I use it" - which suggests you at least want to know how the Guava version would be used. You could model your API on ComparisonChain, only implementing the bits of it you need. I've explained to you the fundamental way it would work... what more do you need? I'm not going to just implement it all for you...

Comment: I am not asking you to implement it. You suggested to implement ComparisonChain but you gave Guava example. I was more looking for a generic ComparatorChain comparison.

Comment: @Nomad: Guava *is* a generic ComparisonChain. It happens to be in Guava, that's all. It's hard to know what you're really looking for that I haven't already provided. The examples and user guide show you how you'd use it if you had Guava - so work out which of those features you need to support, and build that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help. Will do that.

Answer (score 0):

`public class Employee implements Comparator<Employee>`

This is a wrong (probably not intended) use of the `Comparator` interface. I think you want `Comparable` here.

For sorting by empId, dept and project create a custom comparator that does just that and pass it to the `sort()` method. This comparator would then just check the properties you want to compare by in the order you need and return the result when it is not 0 for the first time - or at the end if all properties are equal.

Example:

```
new Comparator<Employee>() {
  public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
    //check if both are not null

    int result = e1.empId.compareTo( e2.empId );

    if( result == 0) {
      result = e1.dept .compareTo( e2.dept );
    }

    ...

    return result;
  }
}
```